# Sql problema con fecha en store procedure

Tags: sql

Soy un poco novato en el tema y queria consultar el siguiente tema ya que tengo varios dias sin obtener la respuesta .

Me encuentro realizando un procedimiento almacenado para un reporte donde trae un listado segun la fecha colocada en el where .

El problema es que los registros en la tabla tienen la fecha y hora .

si coloco unicamente la fecha exacta pero sin la hora y segundos no devuelve resgistros

Existe alguna manera sencilla de filtrar el where solo con la fecha sin hora y minutos ??

les agradezco

```html
select *
from Test as a
WHERE a.dpercierre = '2018-10-31 23:00:29.000'
```

Comment: Hay varias formas de hacer esto, esta es una: `select *
from Test as a
WHERE convert(varchar(10),a.dpercierre,111) = '2018/10/31'`

Comment: como tienes  declarado dpercierre? has ejecutado la query del store procedure directamente sobre la base de datos?

Comment: WHERE convert(varchar(10),a.dpercierre,111) = '2018/10/31' una consulta que tipo de variable debo colocarle al parametro datetime o date o varchar ??

Comment: @MarceloMP coloca la fecha como `varchar`, si te fijas esta en comillas simples.... y la conversión te esta diciendo que es `varchar` : `convert(varchar(10),a.dpercierre,111)`

Comment: Marcelo, es fundamental en tu pregunta, que indiques que motor de base de datos estas usando.

Comment: estoy usando SQL server 2019 .

Comment: select * from Test as a WHERE convert(varchar(10),a.dpercierre,111) = '2018/10/31'   como puedo convetirlo a 31/10/2018

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios ,solo cambio del 111 a 103 les agradezco mucho .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el where de tu consulta podrías castear la fecha a yyyy-mm-dd:

```
SELECT *
FROM Test as a
WHERE convert(varchar, a.dpercierre, 23) = '2018-10-31'
```

Saludos!